# Обращение к файлу по очереди

Tags: php

Есть функция проверяющая нового пользователя, она сверяет его ID, заменяет старый ник на новый (если требуется) или записывает нового пользователя (если такого нету в списке). Все данные храню в json.
По скольку в функции выполняется много действий, нужно запретить к ней доступ, до тех пор, пока она не завершится.
Суть проблемы, что если несколько пользователей стучатся одновременно в эту функцию, то файл json форматируется под ноль.

Вот пример функции:

```js
function checknewuser($currentname, $id) {

  $json = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'users.json');
  $data = json_decode($json, true);

  // действия над пользователем

  file_put_contents('users.json',
  json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), LOCK_EX);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если пользователей много то хранить их в файле абсурд, но это не мое дело конечно.

Для вашей задачи вам потребуется заблокировать файл для параллельной записи

```
function checknewuser($currentname, $id)
{
    // открываем файл
    $fp = fopen("users.json", "r+");

    if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) { // выполняем эксклюзивную блокировку

        // читаем файл
        $user = fread($fp, filesize('users.json'));

        // действия над пользователем ........

        // записываем новые данные
        fwrite($fp, $user);

        // очищаем вывод перед отменой блокировки
        fflush($fp);

        // снимаем блокировку
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
    } else {
        echo "Не удалось получить блокировку!";
    }

    // закрываем файл
    fclose($fp);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.filesystem.php здесь документация по всех методах работы сфайлами

Comment: Вышло не совсем то. Попробую было более подробно показать функцию, так как в данном способе считывается с файла не array, а всё в строку. При данном способе "r+" - постоянно записываются новые данные в файл без очистки прежнего содержимого, а при "w+" - ошибка "fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0" и файл очищается.
(пытался вставить код функции, превышен лимит символов)

Comment: c+ модификатор попробуйте, а для очистки файла `ftruncate()`

Answer (score 0):

Первым действием в функции создайте пустой файл блокировки wr.lock для примера.
В конце удаляйте этот файл.
Перед началом выполнения функции проверяйте его существование если нет выполняем, если есть ждём или сообщаем об ошибке.

Answer (score -1):

Перед запуском `$json = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'users.json');` переименуйте файл под другим именем, считайте переименованный файл, измените данные, запишите их в файл и переименуйте его назад. 
Если первичное переименование завершится любой ошибкой - выведите сообщение, что файл заблокирован на запись или подождите какой-то интервал времени и попробуйте снова.

Но обратите внимание на совет @Arendach и попробуйте хранить данные о пользователях в БД.

Comment: Понял, что обычным способом не решить эту проблему.
Буду переходить на БД

Comment: @Lexa_Coronos Но не забывайте, что в  БД также нужно использовать блокировки.

Comment: Где можно подробнее почитать об этом?

Comment: @Miron у пользователей в БД есть идентификатор и то что запись будут редактировать одновременно вероятность наверно 1 к миллиарду. пустая трата времени. даже если словить ошибку то ничего не произойдет, остальные пользователи останутся в целости и сохранности.

Comment: @Arendach если в БД одна таблица и все действия можно уложить в один запрос, тогда блокировки, безусловно, не нужны. Но обычно при обновлении пользователей задействуется несколько таблиц, чтение, обновление, вставка и вот тут уже можно словить очень много неприятностей при одновременных запросах без блокировок.